# mailcore2 library file size is way too big

Tags: size, mailcore2

I am using mailcore2 for a while now, but I am running into the problem that the library file size is way too big at the extend that can't even commit my code to Github. Does somebody know a workarround or a way to reduce this library in size?

I installed mailcore2 through my podfile with "use_frameworks!", and I went through all the steps of the bridging header file.

Thanks in advance